# /etc/profile missing end to balance this if statement

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

When I wanted to configure environment variables for JAVA on Linux. I added some sentences to the file, `/etc/profile`.
Now the content in it is as follow.

```
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).

if [ "$(id -u)" -eq 0 ]; then
  set PATH "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
else
  set PATH "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
fi
export PATH


if [ "${PS1-}" ]; then
  if [ "${BASH-}" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "$(id -u)" -eq 0 ]; then
      set PS1 '# '
    else
      set PS1 '$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi

export JAVA_HOME=/home/co-eda/Downloads/jdk-18.0.1.1
export CLASSPATH=.:${JAVA_HOME}/lib/dt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
```

then I use
`source /etc/profile`
to renew the environment variables and got this error

```
/etc/profile (line 30): Missing end to balance this if statement
    if [ -r $i ]; then
    ^
from sourcing file /etc/profile
    called on line 185 of file /usr/share/fish/config.fish
in function '.' with arguments '/etc/profile'
```

Does anyone has an idea why this happens and how to modify this code so that I can run it smoothly? I will appreciate it if I can have an answer.

Comment: Your current shell appears to be [fish](https://fishshell.com/), not bash. If you expect it to be bash you should probably use the `chsh` command to make bash your default shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening because you are trying to source `/etc/profile` from `fish` shell. `fish`'s conditional statements are not compatible with `sh`/`bash`/`zsh` and other Bourne-compatible shells. i.e. `fish` is *not* a Bourne-compatible shell.

This file (`/etc/profile`) is intended to be used by Bourne-compatible shells only, as specified by the comment block at the top

> ```
> # /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
> # and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).
> ```

If you simply want to renew your environment variables for the *current* terminal window, try running this -

```
exec sh
. /etc/profile
exec fish
```

If you want to renew the environment variables for *all* applications, you need to logout and login.